# can't get value from a pressed

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Hi' I'm trying to get value with jquery with no success.

This part of the code I get with ajax and it's changes (it's part of a loop in function.php)

```
if ($termschildren) {
    echo '<ul class="BlaBla">';
        foreach ( $termschildren as $termchildren ) {
            echo '<li class="BlaBlaLi">';
                echo '<a href="#" class="tax-filter-children" title="' . $c_term_name->slug . '" data-filter=".pcat'.$taxonomy_id.'.pcat'.$c_term_name->term_id.'">' . $c_term_name->name . '</a>';
            echo '</li>';
    echo '</ul>';
} else {
    echo '&nbsp;';
}
die();
```

the ajax is return to a div called 'childrens_world'

```
echo '<div class="childrens_world">';
    echo '&nbsp;'; //for start
echo '</div>';
```

this is the jquery I use. I can't get the data-filter value. (the loop is fine, in the source code i see it well)

```
$filterLinksChildren = $('.tax-filter-children');
$('.childrens_world').on("click", $filterLinksChildren, function(e) {
    var filt = $filterLinksChildren.data('filter');
    //do something;
)};
```

I use the data-filter (var filt) to send to isotope jquery function

Thanks for any help

Comment: Have you tried `$('.childrens_world').on("click", '.tax-filter-children',function(e) {...etc`

Comment: Then inside that you would have `var filt = $(this).data('filter');`

Comment: bind click to created element class `childrens_world` is dynamically added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of minor fixes:

- Make the following as a string variable as opposed to a jQuery selector.
  From:
   `$filterLinksChildren = $('.tax-filter-children');`

  To

  `filterLinksChildren = '.tax-filter-children';`
- There's apparently a small typographical error towards the end of the function:

  `)};` should actually be `});`

So, your complete solution would be something like the following:

```js
filterLinksChildren = ".tax-filter-children";
$('.childrens_world').on("click", filterLinksChildren, function(e) {
   alert($(this).data("filter"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="childrens_world">
  <ul class="BlaBla">
     <li class="BlaBlaLi">
       <a href="#" class="tax-filter-children" data-filter="a1">a1
       </a>
     </li>
    <li class="BlaBlaLi">
       <a href="#" class="tax-filter-children" data-filter="a2">a2
       </a>
     </li>
    <li class="BlaBlaLi">
       <a href="#" class="tax-filter-children" data-filter="a3">a3
       </a>
     </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="childrens_world">
  <ul class="BlaBla">
     <li class="BlaBlaLi">
       <a href="#" class="tax-filter-children" data-filter="b1">b1
       </a>
     </li>
    <li class="BlaBlaLi">
       <a href="#" class="tax-filter-children" data-filter="b2">b2
       </a>
     </li>
    <li class="BlaBlaLi">
       <a href="#" class="tax-filter-children" data-filter="b3">b3
       </a>
     </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for everyone :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try an alternate to get `data` value. Use `attr`

```
var filt = $filterLinksChildren.attr('data-filter');
```